# When I run envoyproxy I get a GLIBC_2.29 and GLIBC_2.30 not found error | Oracle Cloud (ARM - Ampere Processor) with Oracle Linux 8

Tags: envoyproxy

When I try to execute envoy then I get the following error on Oracle Cloud ARM processor (ARM - Ampere Processor) on Oracle Linux 8:

```
envoy: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by envoy)
envoy: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by envoy)
```

How can I fix this? I have tried multiple guides (one guide was: https://github.com/jueve/build-glibc) but I can't bring it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [Oracle Linux 8 (x86_64) BaseOS Latest](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/x86_64/index.html) comes with `glibc-2.28` whereas [Oracle Linux 9 (x86_64) BaseOS Latest](https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/baseos/latest/x86_64/index.html) has `glibc-2.34`. You may need to upgrade your Oracle Linux or build Envoy yourself.

Comment: Thank you. It works out of the box with Oracle Linux 9.